# How to call action with parameters of JSP Servlet from JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

```
function printthis()
{ 
 var content_vlue = document.getElementById('print_content').innerHTML;
 var target= 'printValue?value1='+content_vlue;
 document.forms[0].action = target;
 document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

`<div id="print_content">hello i am good</div>`

For frontend I am using JSP. While executing this code to get the value in servlet

```
String msg = request.getParameter("value1");
```

While executing this code the browser url changes to ***printValue?***

But I am unable to get the value of *value1*

Please suggest me...

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are missing `value1='+content_vlue` from the request
try this and see

```
var target= "'printValue?value1="+content_vlue+"'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden variable inside your form like this

```
<form ..>
    ....
    <input type="hidden" id="value1" name="value1"/>
</form>
```

and modify javascript function to this .

```
function printthis()
{ 
 var content_vlue = document.getElementById('print_content').innerHTML;
 document.getElementById('value1').value  = content_value;
 var target= 'printValue';
 document.forms[0].action = target;
 document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Hope this will work for you.